# Mongo Data not expiring

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I'm trying to insert a record in mongo that expires in sometime.

```
getMessagesCollection().ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("createdAt", 1), new BasicDBObject("expireAfterSeconds", 10));
```

I insert my data like this

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("_id", mongoMessage.getObjectId());
// Other code
map.put("createdAt", new Date());
getMessagesCollection().insert(convertToDBObject(map))
```

the field createdAt is a date and before inserting the object looks like this

```
{ "_id" : "551bf9b72bea951ecf53fc5f" , "createdAt" : { "$date" : "2015-04-01T09:59:19.723Z"} , ...}
```

But the record is not getting deleted. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're incorrectly creating the date.

Check out how it's done [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/#dates-times)

```
Date now = new Date();
BasicDBObject time = new BasicDBObject("ts", now);
```